# How to load different PDF files in a UIViewController depending on the selection of tableView cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm doing an iPhone application which loads 14 different PDF files upon clicking on their individual table cells. Two ViewController have been created and a UIWebview is used to load the PDF files. 
My problem is that upon clicking on every table cell leads me to the same PDF file. Is it possible to provide me any references or source codes which I can refer to? Please help!

---

```
#import "IssueDetailViewController.h"
#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "Issues.h"
#import "IssueCell.h"

@interface IssueDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation IssueDetailViewController
@synthesize issueItem;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"network_38" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
webview.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight); 
[webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];

}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
IssueView = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:       (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
IssueDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[IssueDetailViewController alloc] init];



[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void) viewWIllAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

}


-(void) setIssueItem:(Issues *)i
{
issueItem = i;
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:[issueItem issueName]];
}




@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set only one PDF to open in your web-view.

Solution - Get the selectedRow and send out the integer(0-14) and catch this on your web-view and based on the selected-row load up your pdf.